# Как объединить учетные записи (сделать единую статистику на двух аккаунтах Stack Overflow)?

Tags: поддержка

Так получилось, что я создал два аккаунта на [StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com):

1. Вход через контакт
2. Вход через google

Есть ли возможность объединить статистику с двух аккаунтов в один ?

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на вашу вторую учетную запись.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272171/sergey

Comment: Оставлю ссылку на статью в справке для тех у кого будет такая же проблема: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв! Я объединил ваши учетные записи.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а сейчас авторизация через гугл у меня будет или через контакт ?

Comment: @Sergey Должно работать и то, и другое.

Comment: @Sergey или ни то, ни другое. Так что выходите аккуратненько.